# Google Fitness API returning Error 500

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-apis-explorer

Is someone aware that the Google Fitness API is returning Error 500, at least for the endpoint:

`https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset` ?

I was testing my app, and keep getting Error 500 since about 7 hours ago. also have tried the Google API Explorer for the same method (taken the necessary previews steps for authorisation):

```
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/fitness/v1/fitness.users.dataset.aggregate?userId=me&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A++%2522aggregateBy%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++%255D%252C%250A++%2522endTimeMillis%2522%253A+%25221529467200000%2522%252C%250A++%2522startTimeMillis%2522%253A+%25221529899200000%2522%250A%257D&
```

And this is the reponse:

```
cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  122
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 28 Jun 2018 17:12:12 GMT
expires:  Thu, 28 Jun 2018 17:12:12 GMT
server:  GSE
vary:  Origin, X-Origin

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

I landed here when I was navigating looking for Google Support from the Google API Explorer page. So, I hope someone sees this :)

Comment: As you probably already know, a 500 error is a generic server-side error -- and not your code's fault. You may want to get in touch with Google about this.

Comment: Yeah... in the google support pages say that these problems are to be reported here, using the respective tags to help the google engineers to pick them up.

Comment: Can you link to the page that mentions this? That feels like a misuse of SO on their part.